# php curl post missing parameters

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a curl request to get some information about database and stuff, but since some user need to query many bases and most of them are not familiar with any kind of shell,
we are trying to build a small page to e"xecute the query and be more user friendly

we got pretty much everything working (form and stuff) but we got really figure how to build the uery in php

here is the original working curl request we made:

> curl  -s - X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' -H
>   'Accept:application/json' -d '{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"} -k
>   https:myurl -u user:password

and here is the code with the request we are trying to build:

```
<?php
$data = array('param1' => 'value1',
              'param2' => 'value2'
             );
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://myurl";
curl_setopt($ch, curlopt_url, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,curlopt_userpwd, "user:password" );
curl_setopt($ch,curlopt_post, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,curlopt_postfuelds, $data);
curl_setopt($ch,curlopt_returntransfer, true);
curl_setopt($ch,curlopt_ssl_verifypeer, false);
curl_setopt($ch,curlopt_httpheader,
    array ("Content-type:application/json"));
$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

I cannot really figure whats wrong? can you help me?
 I rather not use shell_exec with the curl inside because the server hosting is on windows, and we don't have curl.exe available

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: `curlopt_postfuelds` should be `curlopt_postfields`